# Tekken 7, restore customizations after account sharing, PS4

Tags: ps4, tekken-7

I was using friends account with tekken 7 to try it out through acc sharing feature. Later on i decided to buy my own version of tekken and did it, but i've bought deluxe edition instead. The problem is that i've lost all my character and player customization (the latter are rank specific and that's the problem actually). Is there any way to restore them beside de-ranking and ranking up back? My online rank is the same as i was playing on my account, so network related "progress" is actually there.

Answer (score 3):

Only online progress will retain for all machines you've used your account with. This is helpful if you're only focused on ranked matchmaking and less on customs.

Offline progress and items (Offline rank from treasure battles, customizations, fight money, story mode progress) are reset once you use your PSN on another machine.